# Remote Desktop Project in C

Tags: c, remote-desktop, rdp

I want to make project for my final year in college.
So someone suggested me to make Remote Desktop in C.
Now I know basic socket functions for windows in C i.e. I know how to make
echo server in C.
But I don't know what to do next. I searched on internet but couldn't find
something informative.
Could someone suggest me how to approach from this point..any tutorial...or any source ?

Comment: given 'I know how to make echo server in C', I would recommend something a scosch less challenging.

Comment: Do you have a specific target OS in mind?

Comment: @KevinDTimm - there is existing open code to study for this, its not out of the realm of feasibility. Additionally 'pick the protocol out of the implementation' is a great exercise.

Comment: @Tim - but 'Remote Desktop in C' is a far cry from picking the protocol.  something as simple as an echo server is cut/paste from 'let me google that for you.com' - not so for a Remote Desktop

Comment: I think a Remote Desktop in C is about the right size for a final *year* project. A chat server wouldn't really merit a year. Making a remote desktop system and making a robust remote desktop system like VNC or Terminal Server is not the same thing. You could use simple compression methods and so forth. This would probably be a good project for you to learn about some interesting networking problems. Just don't try to beat VNC out of the gate, try to make it work first, then make it faster, better quality, and more secure if you like. Try to go without looking at VNC, it's a bit complex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is do-able. For a college project, you don't need to have something as complex and as full-featured as VNC. Even demonstrating simple keyboard and mouse control and screen feedback would be enough, in my opinion, and that's well within reach.

If you're doing everything from scratch and using Win32, you can get the remote screen using the regular "printscreen" example all around the internet.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/Screen_Capture__Win32_.aspx has it, for one. You can then compress the image with a third-party library, or just send it raw; this wouldn't be very efficient but it would still be a viable demonstration.

Apart from capturing the screen data remotely and showing it in the local window, you'll need to listen for local window messages for mouse and keyboard events, send them to the remote host, and then play them back. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx will probably do that for you.

Comment: I agree with this, although for a college project, you need to do something much more significant than just copy & paste codeproject. But it can give you a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

For sending the image of the screen I would probably use rtp. The [JRTPLIB](http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/~jori/page/index.php?n=CS.Jrtplib) is really handy for that.

And yes, as KevinDTimm says, an echo server is the very easiest part.

Answer (score 0):

Check [tightvnc](http://www.tightvnc.com/) TightVNC is a free remote control software package. The source code is also available.

Answer (score 0):

KevinDTimm may well be right, writing an RDP client would a fairly significant undertaking. To give you some idea, the current spec, available at the top of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc240445(PROT.10).aspx), is 419 pages long and includes references to several additional documents for specific aspects of RDP like Audio Redirection and Clipboards.

Comment: Yeah, but that is for a full remote desktop client. For a college project, you could just omit things like audio redirection.